# Django Exporting CSV giving error of HttpResponse

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I have written code in Django to export the csv file of all the data which is stored in Django database.
However while achieving this I came across this error and it is not getting solved.

I am writing down all the necessary code which I edited for exporting the csv.

views.py

```
def export(request):
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')

writer = csv.writer(response)
writer.writerow(['Item Name', 'Vendor Name', 'Date', 'Inward Registry Number'])

for fields in Form1.objects.all().values_list('item', 'vendor', 'date','inward'):
    writer.writerow(fields)

response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="fields.csv"'
```

urls.py (Under my django-app)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("export/", views.export, name='export'),
]
```

I have made no changes in models.py still posting it here for reference

models.py

```
from django.db import models  

# Create your models here.
class Form1(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    inward = models.IntegerField(default=1234)
    date = models.DateField()
    def __str__(self):
      return self.item
```

For testing purpose I am going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/export/ to check if excel sheet gets downloaded or not.

And I am getting this error their :

[image]

Let me know how to fix it and one more thing which if you know answer to you can tell,

How can I make the font of excel as different, or bold so that it gets downloaded in more readable manner ?

Thanks

Comment: You do not seem to be actually _returning_ the `response` object. Are you sure this is the entirety of the `export` function?

Comment: What should I return then @Kendas?

Comment: The first question on your mind should be what you are returning now. The error tells you that it expects a `HttpResponse` to be returned but received `None` instead. This means either that you return `None` or do not return anything (which has the same effect).